# how to get view from api response on laravel 5.4 or 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.4

**Sample**

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function show ($id)
    {
        return new ProductResource(Product::find($id));
    }
}

Route::get('/products/{id}', 'ProductController@show');

now how i get the route products/id

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to add some requirments:

On api.php route add this line

#### Route :

```
Route::get('api/products/{id}', 'ProductController@show');
```

Via POSTMAN | cURL : http://example.com/api/products/1